# C++ pass a .txt file which has a function name and the parameter

Tags: c++, command-line, argv, argc

I am working on a simple homework that requires me to pass a .txt file which contains 2 lines, the first is the function name, the second is a number, 3, or 9 for example.

I am asking how to pass argv[0] as the function name and argv[ 1] as the parameter.

I'm not sure how to implement this so I get essentially what is in the first screen (I know that it is wrong).

[First screen shot, bad syntax but this is what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJbgZ.jpg)

I have started with what is in the second screen,

[second screen shot, this seems like it should work, but I can't seem to test it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzEV5.jpg)

but I also can't figure out how to pass the .txt in the developer command window to test it. Using Windows Developer Command Prompt. (The program was created in Visual Studio 2015)
I navigate to the debug folder, ...debug>Program "textFile"

This runs the program but does not seem to be taking the file

I have done a TON of searching to try to find some answers, but so far have not found anything that answers this, found a lot of how to pass files for arguments and such, but nothing to address this specifically.

Comment: Please post the text of your programming texts, not images.  Also, **edit** your question with the text, don' put into comments.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I am new I thought that was going to display the images inline.  Any hints on my question while I work on editing this to make it more clear?

Comment: Visual studio 2015 is my IDE

Comment: Use `argv[]` to get a filename from command line arguments.

Comment: Yes I am using argv[], am am asking how to pass argv[0] as the function name and argv[1] as the parameter

Comment: Groovy. Open the project's property page (right click the project and click properties on the pop-up menu) then type your argument strings into  Configuration Properties->Debugging->Command Arguments

Comment: @pppear It is possible to display images in-line I believe. However, text for your code is always better. It's not possible to copy/paste text from an image file (easily).

Answer (score 0):

You have two alternatives:  1) Pass the filename and number; or 2) Pass the file stream and number.

For example:

```
void Read_File(const std::string filename,
               unsigned int number)
{
  std::ifstream input(filename.c_str());
  //...
}

void Read_From_Stream(std::istream& input,
                      unsigned int number)
{
  // ...
}

int main(void)
{
  Read_File("my_file.txt", 24);
  std::ifstream another_file("your_text_file.txt);
  Read_From_Stream(another_file, 42);
  // ...
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I was told I didn't need to worry about filestream, it should just call argc and/or agrv in my code

Comment: You can't call `argv` in your code.  You can read text from it, but you need some kind of function or data structure to represent a file.  In C++, that is done by the filestream classes.